# Is it trivial enough to ignore constants in limes

Tags: limits

I want to show that the limit below is equal to zero. However, I am unsure if its trivial enough to say that the "1" can be neglected for big "n", since these are only constants.

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{2^n+1}{3^n-1} = 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{2^n}{3^n} = 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n = 0
$$
and since $\frac{2}{3} < 1$, then raising it by the power $n \rightarrow \infty$ this limit is equal to zero.

Comment: If you carefully compute the limit of the ratio of the original over your $2^n/3^n$ you can justify that the constants don't matter in this case. But note one cannot always just ignore constants... depends on the problem.

Comment: the step that you miss is not hard. just divide both numerator and denominator by $3^n$, you will have in both sides 1/3^n which goes to 0 clearly.

Comment: The way to say that $1$ is small is to explicitly compare it: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n+1}{3^n-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)}{3^n\left(1-\frac{1}{3^n}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{2^n}}{1-\frac{1}{3^n}}$$ where the latter limit is $1$.

Comment: It works a bit more generally than that. You may take the limit of the ratio of dominating terms in the numerator and denominator if there is any. And by dominating, I mean the ratio of all other terms in the numerator to the dominating term in the numerator (resp. denominator) tends to 0. For example $$\dfrac{2^n+n^{100}+\log(n)}{3^n-600n^5-2} \to 0$$
as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rigorous (and general) manner of "neglecting" something is to use the $\sim$ relation : $2^n+1 \sim  2^n$ and $3^n-1 \sim  3^n$ therefore $
\frac{2^{n}+1}{3^{n}-1} \sim \frac{2^{n}}{3^{n}}
$ so these two sequences have the same limit.

In a more basic way,  you can just factor by the dominant terms it will always work. Here you can write

$$
\frac{2^{n}+1}{3^{n}-1} = \frac{2^{n}(1+\frac{1}{2^n})}{3^{n}(1-\frac{1}{3^n})} 
$$
Then

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{n}}\right)} = 1
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{n}+1}{3^{n}-1}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{n}}{3^{n}}
$$

It's obvious here even without doing the math, so the level of justification expected will depend on your level of study and what your teacher expects (if it's for a school setting).

Comment: I would only need to caution the OP that, even though $a_n\sim b_n$ and $c_n\sim d_n$ *does* mean that $a_nc_n\sim b_nd_n$, and in most cases it also means $\frac{a_n}{c_n}\sim\frac{b_n}{d_n}$, it does *not* mean $a_n+c_n\sim b_n+d_n$ nor it means $a_n-c_n\sim b_n-d_n$.